# UITableView and UINavigationBar in UIPopoverController causes UI bug

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uinavigationbar, uipopovercontroller

I have a `UITableView` in `UIViewController` and I have embeddded in via Interface Builder to Navigation Controller. I present this view controller inside a `UIPopoverController`. Everything works fine until I start scrolling. The cells overlap the navigation bar, see the picture below. How can I solve this? Functionally everything works fine but this doesn't look good.

[image]